# iterate exploded values

Tags: php, explode, loops

I am unable to reiterate the exploded lat and lng values. Keeps returning only one pair of (x,y) values in the database.

Please see the code below:

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents("http://api.geograph.org.uk/syndicator.php?key=hfALmNnpQ&i=14102530&page=1&format=media&expand=1&perpage=100");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
foreach ($xml->item as $entry){
echo $entry->title;
echo $entry->description;
echo $entry->link;

// use that namespace
$dc = $entry->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
$georss = $entry->children('http://www.georss.org/georss');
echo $entry->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')->creator;
echo $entry->children('http://www.georss.org/georss')->point
list($lat,$lng) = explode(' ', $entry->children('http://www.georss.org/georss')->point);
}
?>
```

The code below shows the database operations:

```
<?php
require 'table.php';

// Opens a connection to a PostgresSQL server
$connection = pg_connect("dbname=postgis user=postgres password=****");


// Execute query        

foreach ($xml->item as $entry) { 

$query = "INSERT INTO geognew(title, link, author, latitude, longitude) VALUES ('" . $entry->title . "', '" . $entry->link . "', '" . $entry->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')->creator . "', '" . $lat . "', '" . $lng . "')";

$result = pg_query($query);
printf ("These values are inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $entry->title, $entry->link, $entry->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')->creator, $lat, $lng);
}

pg_close();

?>
```

Thanks
Yemi

Comment: Given there's no database operations inside that loop, you'd only ever get **1** lat/long pair after the loop exits, which is the LAST pair processed by the loop.

Comment: Show the output of your `echo` statements.

Comment: @MarcB I have edited the post. See code showing database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better you save the lat/lng in an array. Because iterating the xml over and over is a overkill.

```
// define this $points outside the foreach loop
$points = array();

foreach(...){
....
    list($lat,$lng) = explode(' '
           , (string)($entry->children('http://www.georss.org/georss')->point));
    $points[] = array('lat'=> $lat, 'long' => $lng);
}
```

Here is a full code that iterates only through latitude and longitude.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$namespaces = $xml->getNameSpaces(true);
foreach ($xml->item as $entry){
    $georss = $entry->children($namespaces['georss']);
    list($lat,$lng) = explode(' ', (string)$georss->point);
    echo "$lat, $lng\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestion didn't iterate the values. Keeps returning same pair of lat, lng values.

Comment: Thanks for the code. The lat and lng values now iterate. But in order to insert them into my database, i am not sure if how i declared the variable in the code that contains my database connection is correct.

Comment: When I run the code that supports the database connection, all  other iterated values return correctly. But as for the lat and long, only the  last pair (x,y) processed by the loop is replicated into the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you see my second code? use it to parse the lat long and save it to array. Then insert into db.

Comment: See [this](http://pastie.org/3533706) code. This will insert lat and long on each iteration. I have added the lat long parsing code for you. But you have the code to parse title, description, link etc!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `SimpleXmlElement::item()` being defined in the class. Do yea mean `SimpleXmlElement::children?`

which mean:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $entry) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand you

Comment: What i mean is $xml->item is not a valid function of class SimpleXmlElement